# Making an a tag active in nextjs on changing link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have 2 pages Home page and About us page where the links for both end in /home and /about respectively. The landing page is my home page so I have set the css property for that to active so it highlights. But when I go to my about page the home page css stays active. How do I dynamically change the css when my route changes in nextJs?

My current Code:

```
export default function Nav({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Legacy</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
      </Head>
      <nav>
        <div className="logo">Legacy</div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="click" />
        <label for="click" className="menu-btn">
          <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
          <Link href="http://localhost:3000/home">
            <a className="active" >
              Home
            </a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link href="http://localhost:3000/about">
            <a >About Us</a>
            </Link>
          </li>              
        </ul>
      </nav>          
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). The router is a hook, so it updates every time the page changes.

Here's a short example:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Nav() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const currentRoute = router.pathname

  return (
    <Link href='/about'>
      <a className={currentRoute === '/about' ? 'active' : ''}>
        About us
      </a>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

I'd also recommend checking out the docs as there's much more you can do with the router:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

---

P.S. When creating relative links, it's best to not include the domain. So instead of `http://localhost:3000/about`, just use `/about`. It will always work, and if you ever decide to change the domain (e.g., deploying the site with Vercel), you won't need to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something similar to this if you are using Next13.4 onwards

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";
export default function NavBar() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
    <div className={styles["nav-container"]}>
      <div className={styles["nav-logo"]}>
        <Image
          height={50}
          width={50}
          src="/logo.png"
          className="logo"
          alt="logo"
        />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.nav}>
        <div className={`${styles.links}`}>
          <Link
            href="/"
            key="/"
            className={`${
              "/" == pathname ? styles["text-blue"] : styles["text-black"]
            }`}
          >
            Home
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.links}`}>
          <Link
            href="/services"
            key="/services"
            className={`${
              "/services" == pathname
                ? styles["text-blue"]
                : styles["text-black"]
            }`}
          >
            Services
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.links}`}>
          <Link
            href="/contact-us"
            key="/contact-us"
            className={`${
              "/contact-us" == pathname
                ? styles["text-blue"]
                : styles["text-black"]
            }`}
          >
            Contact Us
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.links}`}>
          <Link
            href="/about-us"
            key="/about-us"
            className={`${
              "/about-us" == pathname
                ? styles["text-blue"]
                : styles["text-black"]
            }`}
          >
            About
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```